# how to debug .NET code and find the root cause of the exception

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I tried to install the Nuget.Server Nuget package and execute it, but I get the following error:

```
 [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values..
Paramter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Specified argument was out of the range of valid values..
Paramter name: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

How can I diagnose the root cause?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install the Nuget server?  Did you follow the instructions here? http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds  In particular, did you creae a new Empty Web Application? (not Web Site)?

Answer (score -3):

If I understand you rught, you need Stack Trace. In the time of debug open it: Debug/Windows/Call Stack. But you don't have access to source of Nuget.Server, so I think 
you don't see direct problem string of code.

Comment: -1 The OP has just posted the stack trace. That's not what they need